# RestKit: Can pathPattern have multiple IDs (Object Attributes + Object Relationship Attributes)

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, cocoapods, restkit-0.24.x

I have nested resource endpoints like `/users/:userID/profiles/:profileID` from my backend.

In my data model i have the same relationships setup as following:
`User` -- `has-many` -- `profiles`.
So is there any way i could setup my router to fetch object attributes from the original object's (say a user) relationship.
I have the proper relationships setup as well as inverse relationships.

At the end i want to use it like this:

```
[allRoutes addObject:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Profile class] pathPattern:@"/users/:userID/profiles/:profileID/set_inactive" method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

Comment: I haven't tried before, but try `/users/:userID/profiles/:profile.profileID` and see what happens

Comment: are you sure i need to do `:profile.profileID` and not `:profiles.profileID`. because the relationship is named `profiles`.

Comment: Yes, it should be the relationship name